# Sending a complex html as the body of email from the command line via an SendGrid API

Tags: bash, command-line-interface, sendgrid

I need to send an HTML file as the body of an eamil to several customers. Our company will be using SendGrid for this, and I need to be able to send the email via API Curl Call.

The way that I'm doing it so far works for simple html or plain text:

```
curl -s --request POST \
--url https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send \
--header "Authorization: Bearer SECRET_API_KEY" \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data '{"personalizations":[{"to":[{"email":"my1@email.com"},{"email":"my2@email.com"}]}],"from":{"email":"info@somewhere.com"},"subject":"Testing sending emails via SendgridAPI","content":[{"type":"text\/html","value":"Test API Email From ME"}]}'
```

Now this works just fine. The problem is when I want to replace 'Test API Email From ME' with the contents of a rather large, complex HTML file. This has all the usual cli nightmares such as a mix of ' and " and new lines everywhere. I need to sanatize the HTML in order to accomplish three things:

1. The final result needs to be a valid command line string
2. The --data switch argument needs to remain a valid JSON enconded string
3. The HTML should not break.

What I do is I create the actual string command and the execute it using a scripting language. So I can perform any operation that I want on the html before inserting it in the value field of the content field. So my question is: what are the string operations that I should perform on the html so that I can send the email using this methodology?

Comment: I will show you how to do this with `jq` in a short while

Comment: @LéaGris Thanks, but what is jq? JQuery? Or something else?

Comment: `jq` is a command-line / shell JSON parser processor that is the right too here for your need to produce proper JSON data from raw data like html.

Comment: You have to escape your HTML for it to be a valid JSON string. The easiest way is to use the `jq` command utility.

Comment: @LéaGris Thanks for the clarification. I'll wait for your example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

###### Using `jq` and bash

I'll do it with static data, you may improve upon it

- Define a JSON template for the API:

```sh
IFS='' read -r -d '' json_template <<'EOF'
{
  "personalizations": [
    {
      "to": [
        { "email": "my1@email.com" },
        { "email": "my2@email.com" }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "from": { "email": "info@somewhere.com" },
  "subject": "Testing sending emails via SendgridAPI",
  "content": [
    {
      "type": "text/html",
      "value": "Test API Email From ME"
    }
  ]
}
EOF
```

- Define the HTML content:

```sh
IFS='' read -r -d '' html_email <<'EOF'
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    title>Simple Email</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    Test API Email From ME
  </body
</html>
EOF
```

- Replace the email content in the JSON with the HTML

```sh
json_data=$(
    jq -c -n \
        --arg html "$html_email" \
        --argjson template "$json_template" \
        '$template | .content[0].value = $html'
)
```

- Send the query

```sh
curl -s --request POST \
    --url https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send \
    --header "Authorization: Bearer SECRET_API_KEY" \
    --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    --data "$json_data"
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand anything at all. What is this code supposed to accomplish? Or how is it supposed to fix my issue?

Comment: I updated with the steps; the first two code blocks only store text in bash variables (`json_template` and `html_email`)

Comment: `--data "$json_data"` may exceed the maximum allowed arguments length, so it is safer to pass the data payload as an input stream with `--data @-`

Comment: @LéaGris You're right; in this case I would also have to change `jq --arg html "$html_email"` with some streaming options?

Comment: @Fravadona of course, see my answer: `--rawfile html content.html`

Comment: Thank you very much @Fravadona!!! I manage to make this work with what I'm using. I would love to modify my code using the streaming options, but I 100% understand your example as it matches what I need to do, but I'm a bit lost on what @Léa Gris has done.

Comment: Léa's answer is a robust solution that also has parameters (`recipients` `from` `subject`) that you can set in the bash script instead of hard-coding them in the JSON. As you're not familiar with `jq`, I wrote an answer easy to understand, but it's very basic in comparison. IMO you should use Lea's solution, at least upvote it like me ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can compose a proper JSON data payload with `jq` so it can be sent to the API.

`jq` will ensure every values, recipients, from, subject and the html body will be respectively encoded to proper JSON data objects, arrays and strings before it is submitted as `--data @-` to `curl`:

I added comments everywhere, so it is very clear what is done at every step:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

recipients=(
  'my1@email.com'
  'my2@email.com'
)

from='info@somewhere.com'
subject='Testing sending emails via SendgridAPI'

# Streams null-delimited recipients array entries
printf '%s\0' "${recipients[@]}" |

# jq slurps the null-delimited recipients,
# read the raw html content into the jq $contentHTML variable
# and integrate it all as a proper JSON
jq --slurp --raw-input --rawfile contentHTML example.html \
  --arg from "$from" \
  --arg subject "$subject" \
'
# Fills the jq $recipient JSON array variable
# by splitting the null-delmited entries
# from the incoming stream
split( "\u0000") as $recipients | 

{
  "personalizations": [
    {
      # Uses the $recipients array that has been
      # slurped  from the input stream
      "to": $recipients
    }
  ],
  "from": {

    # Use the $from that has been passed as --arg
    "email": $from
  },

  # Use the $subject that has been passed as --arg
  "subject": $subject,

  "content": [
    {
      "type": "text/html",
      "value": $contentHTML
    }
  ]
}
' |

# Get the resultant JSON piped into curl
# that will read the data from the standard input
# using --data @-
# rather than passing it as an argument, because
# the payload could exceed the maximum length of arguments
curl -s --request POST \
  --url https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send \
  --header "Authorization: Bearer SECRET_API_KEY" \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data @-
```